# Accessing properties of derived classed from interface contract

Tags: c#, oop, interface

I am creating a class library that will be used to create other applications with specific functionality. The library should implement all of the concrete functionality, and the implementing application will add specific business rules to the classes. Typically this is a trivial representation of some objects:

In class library:

```
interface IWheel
{
   int Radius { get; set; }
   string Color { get; set; }
}

abstract class Wheel : IWheel
{
   int Radius { get; set; }
   string Color { get; set; } 
}

interface ICar 
{
   string Color { get; set; }
   List<IWheel> Wheels { get; set; }
}

abstract class Car : ICar 
{
   string Color { get; set; }
   List<IWheel> Wheels { get; set; }

   public Car()
   {
      List<IWheel> Wheels = new List<IWheel>();
   }
}
```

In implementing application business logic:

```
class SpecialWheel : Wheel 
{
    int SpecialWheelProperty { get; set; }
}

class SpecialCar : Car
{
   string SpecialCarProperty { get; set; }
}
```

In implementing application instantiation:

```
SpecialWheel wheel1 = new SpecialWheel { SpecialWheelProperty = 6 };
SpecialWheel wheel2 = new SpecialWheel { SpecialWheelProperty = 6 };
SpecialWheel wheel3 = new SpecialWheel { SpecialWheelProperty = 8 };
SpecialWheel wheel4 = new SpecialWheel { SpecialWheelProperty = 8 };

SpecialCar car = new SpecialCar();
car.Wheels.Add(wheel1);
car.Wheels.Add(wheel2);
car.Wheels.Add(wheel3);
car.Wheels.Add(wheel4);
```

All is good so far, until I try to do something like:

```
// Cant do this as "SpecialWheelProperty" is not in the Interface contract
int wheelSpecialProperty = car.Wheels.First().SpecialWheelProperty;
```

I could of course add the "SpecialWheelProperty" to the IWheel Interface and make it an abstract property of the Wheel class, but this would defeat my final objective of implementing the business logic in derived classes.

I have a few ideas floating round in my head (maybe generics), but, in this case what is the best approach, and an example of that approach?

Comment: If you are so sure that the element will have the `SpecialWheelProperty` could you not use `Cast<SpecialWheel>`? But if that is the case, then why are you using polymorphism at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your code expresses no relationship between the `SpecialCar` and `SpecialWheel` classes, yet expects the interface of `SpecialCar` to expose `SpecialWheel` instances. The fact that you're actually adding all `SpecialWheel` instances is entirely coincidental.

This seems like a task for generics, with the base class accepting a type parameter implementing `IWheel`.

```
abstract class Car<TWheel> : ICar where TWheel : IWheel
{
   string Color { get; set; }
   ICollection<TWheel> Wheels { get; set; }

   public Car()
   {
      Wheels = new List<TWheel>();
   }
}

class SpecialCar : Car<SpecialWheel> {
    // Whatever
}
```

Now you can still do this without losing any type safety:

```
int swp = car.Wheels.First().SpecialWheelProperty;
```

A word of caution: while this technique makes your desired code possible, it can quickly grow out of control if used in deep class hierarchies. Please use sparingly.

Answer (score 0):

So far as I understand a 
    SpecialWheel

Is on the business logic so that appears to be normal to cast to get it specific properties:

```
int wheelSpecialProperty = (car.Wheels.First() as SpecialWheel).SpecialWheelProperty;
```

A question: why do you create a constructor in 
    Car
Since it is abstract?

Comment: Why would an abstract class *not* have a constructor? A constructor initializes the instance, which is just as valid on an instance of an abstract class.

Comment: From my point of view it is no sense to give a constructor on an object you cannot instanciate. Also it breaks the CA1012 rule: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182126.aspx

Comment: Ah you mean that an abstract class should not have a **public** constructor. That makes more sense. Nevertheless, the constructor mentioned in the question still has its value since it initializes a property.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it will be hard to answer this question in one precise way. The problem is to understand your system. Here you only have what I called a "technique". In this case an inheritance and polymorphism. But when you build system, it is usually more than this. You may have a framework, plumbing if you like, where all operations are done on interface level. Factories. Then, in specialized areas, you have business-specific code like this:

```
class CarFactory 
{ 
    public static ICar BuildCar(int kind); 
    if (int == 0)
        return new RegularCar();
    else 
        return new SpecialCar();
}
```

so in your "Special" code you can add special property value

```
SpecialCar sc = (SpecialCar)CarFactory.BuildCar(1); // notice casting
sc.SpecialProperty = "special value";
```

So, only specific clients/consumers will know about special properties. Your application will operate with

```
ICar, IWheel, // etc
```

for example, when you acquire regular car, your client has no idea about 1, only 0.

```
RegularCar rc = (RegularCar)CarFactory.BuildCar(0); // notice casting
```

But the handler that calls "AddWheels" has no idea of what car it is and declared as

```
CarBuilderWheelHandler.AddWheels(ICar c, List<IWheel> w)
```

`CarBuilderWheelHandler` may need to mount tires, inflate and balance each of them. But your special wheel may have installed Tire pressure monitoring system rather than regular valve. In this case your special car has a device to monitor TPMS and knows how to handle special wheel properties. But when it flows from handler to handler, those handlers don't know the specifics of "special" things. Hadlers work with interfaces.

```
void AddWheels(ICar c, List<IWheel> w)
{ 
    MountRubber(w);
    Inflate(w);
    Balance(w);
    c.Wheels = w;
}
```

Then somewhere inside special car, it knows how to monitor pressure

```
void Timer_Tick(...)
{
    foreach(SpecialWheel w in _wheels)
    {
        if w.Pressure < _pressureSetByDriver //'Pressure' is not part of IWheel
            SendPressureWarningToDashboard();
    }
}
```

This is really abstract example, may be only good for you to understand what is purpose of Abstract objects in OOP.

I believe that your question can have many answers and we don't have exact context under which you working